# How to renewal ssl certificate on redbird proxy server

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, redbird

I use redbird proxy server for serve my app. Today expired my certificate.
How I can renewal it? I tried it by this [instruction](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel7-nginx) but looks like it works just with ngnix server.

my `server.js`:

```
const proxy = require('redbird')({
  port: 80,
  xfwd: false,
  letsencrypt: {
    path: "certs",
    port: 4444
  },
  ssl: {
    port: 443
  }
});

proxy.register("domain.com", "http://localhost:3000", {
    ssl: {
      letsencrypt: {
        email: "email@gmail.com",
        production: true
      }
    }
});

proxy.register("www.domain.com", "http://localhost:3000", {
    ssl: {
      letsencrypt: {
        email: "email.com",
        production: true
      }
    }
});
```

folder structure:

```
drwxr-xr-x   8 root    root     4096 Mar 27 22:23 certs 
drwxrwxr-x 157 redbird redbird  4096 Mar 27 21:33 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 redbird redbird   142 Mar 27 21:33 package.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 redbird redbird   887 Aug 23 22:40 server.js
-rw-rw-r--   1 redbird redbird 48105 Mar 27 21:33 yarn.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed `certs` folder and redbird created new `certs` folder with valid certificates.